# Who is Muhammad bin Abi Muhammad (محمد بن أبي محمد)?

Tags: people, ilm-ar-rijal

In the sanad (chain of narrators) of Hadith #16620 in Attabari, one of the narrators is ***Muhammad bin Abi Muhammad (محمد بن أبي محمد)***, I would like to know who is he? what scholars have said in regards to him? and whether he is trustworthy or not.

Here's the Hadith:

> 16620 - حدثنا أبو كريب قال : حدثنا يونس بن بكير قال : حدثنا محمد بن
>   إسحاق قال : **حدثني محمد بن أبي محمد** مولى زيد بن ثابت قال : حدثني سعيد
>   بن جبير ، أو عكرمة ، عن ابن عباس قال : أتى رسول الله صلى الله عليه
>   وسلم سلام بن مشكم ، ونعمان بن أوفى ، وشأس بن قيس ، ومالك بن الصيف ،
>   فقالوا : كيف نتبعك وقد تركت قبلتنا ، وأنت لا تزعم أن عزيرا ابن الله؟
>   فأنزل في ذلك من قولهم : ( وقالت اليهود عزير ابن الله وقالت النصارى
>   المسيح ابن الله ) ، إلى : ( أنى يؤفكون ) .
>
> [Source](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=50&ID=2301)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

محمد بن أبي محمد (Muhammad bin abi Muhammad) is the servant of [Zaid bin Thabit زيد بن ثابت](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaid_bin_Thabit) the famous companion.

He narrated hadiths from [Sa'id ibn Jubayr سعيد بن جبير](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%27id_ibn_Jubayr) and [Ikrimah عكرمة](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%83%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%8A), while [Muhammad ibn Ishaq محمد ابن إسحاق](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Ishaq) narrated hadiths from him.

Scholar [Ibn Habban ابن حبان](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86) mentioned him as a trusted person, while [Al-Dhahabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Dhahabi) said he doesn't know about him.

### Quotes

> 10559 - محمد بن أبى محمد مولى زيد بن ثابت الأنصاري يروى عن سعيد بن جبير وعكرمة روى عنه بن إسحاق
>
> 10559 - Muhammad bin abi Muhammad, servant of Zaid bin Thabit Al-Ansari, narrated from Sa'id ibn Jubayr and Ikrimah, and Ibn Ishaq narrated from him.
>
> الثقات [لابن حبان](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86) The Trustworthy People by Ibn Habban

> 711 - د (أبي داود) محمد بن أبي محمد الانصاري مولى زيد بن ثابت مدني.
>   روى عن سعيد بن جبير وعكرمة. وعنه محمد بن إسحاق. ذكره ابن حبان في
>   الثقات. قلت: وقال الذهبي لا يعرف.
>
> Muhammad bin abi Muhammad, servant of Zaid bin Thabit Al-Ansari, narrated from Sa'id ibn Jubayr and Ikrimah, and Ibn Ishaq narrated from him. Ibn Habban mentioned him in his book "The Trustworthy People". And I say: Al-Dhahabi said that he doesn't know.
>
> تهذيب التهذيب لابن حجر Tahthib Al-Tahthib by [Ibn Hajar Al-Asqalani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Asqalani)

> 5590 - د : محمد بن أَبي محمد الأَنْصارِيّ المدني<sup>4</sup> ، مولى زيد بن ثابت.
>   رَوَى عَن : سَعِيد بن جبير (د) ، وعكرمة مولى ابن عباس (د).
>
> <sup>4</sup>: (4) تاريخ البخاري الكبير : 1 / الترجمة 704 ، والجرح والتعديل : 8 / الترجمة 376 ، وثقات ابن حبان : 7 / 392 ، والكاشف : 3 / الترجمة 5225 ، وميزان الاعتدال : 4 / الترجمة 8129 ، ونهاية السول ، الورقة 350 ، وتهذيب التهذيب : 9 / 433 ،
>   والتقريب : 2 / 205 ، وخلاصة الخزرجي : 2 / الترجمة 6635.
>
> *Translation*
>
> 5590 - Muhammad bin abi Muhammad Al-Ansari Al-Madani<sup>4</sup>, servant of Zaid bin Thabit, narrated from Sa'id ibn Jubayr and Ikrimah, and Ibn Ishaq narrated from him.
>
> <sup>4</sup>: History of Senior Bukhari 1/704, Ajjarh wa Atta'deel 8/376, The Trustworthy Poeple by Ibn Habban 7/392, Al-Kashif 3/5225, Mizan Al-I'tidal 4/8129, Nihaiat Al-soul page 350, Tahthib Al-Tahthib 9/433, Taqrib Al-Tahthib 2/205, The Conclusion of Tahthib Al-Tahthib by Al-Khazraji 2/6635.

There are other sources but they same almost the same thing, and the're referred in the last quote as sources, so I'll not quote from them.